# Issue with API Module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify

I'm working on a project that works with the Spotify API to allow users to search for and add songs/playlists to their account. I'm coding it all in react, and I get to the point where there's no compiler errors, the only error being:

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

Yet nothing on the application seems to work, you can't add songs to playlist, search the playlist, etc. I'm trying to figure out if something is wrong with my API module, because that's the only thing I can think of that has an issue and doesn't throw any errors. The module follows below, or you can view the [repo](https://github.com/BeauRussell/Codecademy-Jammming) And here is the [Spotify API Authorization Document](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#implicit_grant_flow) That we were told to use

```js
function Spotify() {
 function getAccessToken() {
  if(accessToken !== '') {
   return accessToken;
  } else if (window.location.href.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/) != null){
   accessToken = window.location.href.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/);
   expiresIn = window.location.href.match(/expires_in=([^&]*)/);
   window.setTimeout(() => accessToken = '', expiresIn * 1000);
   window.history.pushState('Access Token', null, '/');
  } else {
   window.location = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&response_type=token&scope=playlist-modify-public&redirect_uri=${redirectURI}`;
  }

  async function search(term) {
   accessToken=getAccessToken();
    try {
      let response = await fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=${term}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        }
      });
      if (response.ok) {
        let jsonResponse = await response.json();
        let tracks = jsonResponse.map(track => ({
         id: track.id,
         name: track.name,
         artist: track.artists[0].name,
         album: track.album.name,
         uri: track.uri
        }));
        return tracks;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  function savePlaylist(name, trackURIs) {
   if (name === undefined || trackURIs === undefined) {
    return;
   } else {
    let userAccessToken = getAccessToken();
    let headers = {Authorization: userAccessToken};
    let userId = findUserId(headers);
    let playlistID;
    fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userId}/playlists`, {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      "Content-Type": 'application/json'
     },
     body: {
      name: name
     }
    }).then(response => {return response.json()}
    ).then(playlist => {
     playlistID = playlist.id;
    });
   }
  }

  function findUserId(headers) {
   accessToken = getAccessToken();
   let id;
   fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me`, {headers: headers}
    ).then(response => {return response.json()}
    ).then(jsonResponse => {
     id = jsonResponse[0].id;
    });
    return id;
  }
 }
}

export default Spotify;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with your code:

1. The handleTermChange method in SearchBar.js reads the value from the input incorrectly, it should be: `this.setState({term: event.target.value});`
2. The search button is only a link, you have to bind the onClick event, something like this: `<a onClick={this.search}>SEARCH</a>`
3. Something is not right in Spotify.js, currently the getAccessToken method encapsulates everything else.

If you inspect your playlist with React Dev Tools, you can see, that there is no id property on track in TrackList.js, so it will be always null. This is why you get the warning.

Comment: I made these updates with everything but the id value so far, and get an error when I type anything into the search box that's "Cannot read property 'target' of undefined" with the lane highlighted of the event.target.value, would that be fixed with the id change, or is it something different?

Comment: I don't think your program isn't working because of the warning.
I found this repo while I was searching for your Spotify error message, maybe it can help: [link](https://github.com/JohnHiro84/Jammming/tree/master/src)